# Retrieve last row values from Cassandra, increment it and pass it back to db using post payload

Tags: java, cassandra, rest-assured

I connected to Cassandra database using Java and able to query and read all the values as per my query.
What i want to do now is

1. Write a logic to scan the table and fetch the values of the last row which is SeqNo 3 in this case
2. Once i fetch these values increase the SeqNo by 1, Amount by $10 and Start Date by 1 month and store it in some variable.
3. Pass these new stored value in Post Request Payload which will then insert the new values in db with SeqNo 4
   Program should continue adding new values to db everytime i run my post method payload.

As i mention i am able to get the values from Cassandra but need to know the logic of incrementing it and storing it. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Update the question with queries you are using and schema of the table.

Comment: The query i am using is select * from table where acctno=555; This will give me the all the accounts. Now i need to retrieve all the values from the last row and store it into some variable and increment it.